# Dual boot ubuntu over windows gone wrong

Tags: dual-boot

I tried dual boot ubuntu 14.04 with windows 7 (w7 already installed). I  watched videos and read tutorials which i followed step by step. However, after installing ubuntu and rebooting my pc i noticed that there was not any option whether to choose w7 or ubuntu and run automatically ubuntu. Did i erased windows 7 or i have a chance to load windows again?If i have, can u give me a piece of advice ?
if u need more information about my messy installation please let me know.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: BIOS or (U)EFI installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't necesarily mean you've deleted your Windows installation. In fact, this is a very frequent problem when trying to make a dual boot.

Try using **Boot-Repair**, a tool which fixes this kind of problem.

You just have to boot in Ubuntu and type the following in a terminal to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Once the program is open, just click *"Recommended repair"* and cross your fingers!

If you need any further information, you can take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: That worked perfectly my friend. Thank u very much. You made a man happy today.

Comment: It's great to hear that!